# React/animation - render animation everytime on button click when state or props change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to have the animation work everytime i click on the buttons in the below project

**Code** - https://codesandbox.io/s/8fjs8i

**Description**
There are 3 buttons named first, second and third. when i click on first, the purple box below shows first, when i click on second it shows second and so on, basically the div is updating everytime based on button click.

**Problem :** but the animation fadIn that i have given to the div works only on application load. how can i make it work everytime i click the button so the the box fadesIN with animation for every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Renders = ({ arr }) => {
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoad(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLoad(false);
    }, 1);

  }, [arr]);

  if (load) return <></>;

  return (
    <div className="renders">
      <div className="zoomers">{arr}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @elirand5. this works but could you please explain how it works....i understood that the component return nothing for a mili second and then returns back the div but how is this related to the animation working.

Comment: yes of course, because you render a Fragment element so the other return go out from the dom and then you render it so its loaded restart, its like the first time you load the component, you can set the timeout to bigger value and open the dev tools to see how the changes go, i am sorry about the English :)

Comment: ok so the fundamental concept is that animation only works on fresh component load and not re-render right ?

Comment: yes maybe there is another way to restart the animation, but in this case you unload what return (<div..) and load it again so its must to restart the animation because its a new loading

Answer (score 0):

This another way you can do it:

```
const Renders = ({ arr }) => {
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoad(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
    setLoad(false);
    }, 1);

  }, [arr]);

  return (
    <div className="renders">
      <div className={load ? '' : "zoomers"}>{arr}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now look the different, before you load and unload, now its just a play with the class name, the idea that every time you load element with the animation class so its start to work

Comment: Pervious one is better than this one... I can see the screen blinking in this one there is more delay here

Comment: Ok choose what you want, I just want to show you the idea behind and see another option, maybe for this example the first is better but maybe for something else this will be better